# Variables as Values in Python Dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 4 private variables:

```
__first = 0
__second = 0
__third = 0
__fourth = 0
```

I added them to a dictionary like this:

```
numbers = {one: __first, two: __second, three: __third, fourth: __fourth)
```

When I do `__first += 1`, the value in the dictionary won't get changed while the original variable would.

Any help?

Comment: If `__first` are integers or floats (i..e immutable objects) then, yea, they won't work. Now, you can hold a mutable object, such as a list, and change its value. So if `__first = [0]` and you do `__first[0] = __first[0] + 1`, then it'd update in the dictionary

Comment: Variables can't be dict values. Dict values are always objects, not variables; your `numbers` dict's values are whatever objects `__first`, `__second`, `__third`, and `__fourth` referred to at the time the dict was created.

Comment: The values will never update on the dictionary unless you do it manually. when they change.. use a function instead.

Comment: Okay, so I set the values to zero in the dictionary. But I'm now dealing with another issue. I have two different instances of my class, and when I change the dictionary value of one of the instances, it also changes the other. Why is it overwriting?

Comment: @yaboy_ivy left an answer please tell if its correct and mark it as good if it worked out

Comment: See https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1.html. What you want is fundamentally at odds with Python's data model, and there's not enough context in your question to provide an appropriate workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if this works for you. I Simply Updated the value based on the key. and you get a refresh dictionary. You may be asking youself why If I update the variable they wont update in the dictionary? they will do the first time, but the second time they wont since they are allocated in other block of memory that can only be accesed via index location [x] position. So if you need to update it you may need to update the values based on their key in this case.

```
__first = 0
__second = 0
__third = 0
__fourth = 0

dict = {"first": __first,
        "second": __second,
        "third": __third,
        "fourth": __fourth}


def updateDict(dict, new_key, new_value):

    for key, value in dict.items():
        if key == new_key:
            dict[key] = new_value

    print(dict)

    return dict


dict = updateDict(dict, "first", 1)
# {'first': 1, 'second': 0, 'third': 0, 'fourth': 0}

dict = updateDict(dict, "second", 10)
# {'first': 1, 'second': 10, 'third': 0, 'fourth': 0}
```